# Hosted a site working perfectly locally but online, having issues with dompdf class not being found

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, dompdf

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
```

class Pdf{

I cant generate a pdf from, keeps says dompdf class not found, tried extending CI_Controller, even extending dompdf class still cant resolve.

Comment: Where are you loading the file from? Is this from a controller, model or library? Where is the dompdf file located?
Don't just expect people to know what you want to achieve if you are not very clear with your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using composer then it would be an easy task to add DOM Pdf compatibility in your project. [This](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) is the Repository of DOM Pdf.
You can Install it By using Composer Package Manager

```
composer require dompdf/dompdf
```

And You have to enable Autoload in your Codeigniter Project.

> To autoload resources, open the application/config/autoload.php file
> and add the item you want to load to the autoload array. You’ll find
> instructions in that file corresponding to each type of item.
>
> Additionally, if you want CodeIgniter to use a Composer auto-loader,
> just set $config['composer_autoload'] to TRUE or a custom path in
> application/config/config.php.

And Finally, Set the Path of vendor/autoload.php in application/config/config.php

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Please Check the CI3 Documentation Here https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/autoloader.html